# How do I connect SonarQube to my AWS RDS Microsoft SQL Server instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sonarqube, amazon-rds, sonarqube-ops

I am installing SonarQube and created an AWS RDS Microsoft SQL Server instance.
How do I connect SonarQube to my rds instance with the endpoint?

**Sonar Properties file:**

sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=sonar

sonar.jdbc.username=xxxxx

sonar.jdbc.password=xxxxx

Comment: Consider integrated login. Do have a look at the PDF referenced [here](https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonar-.net-documentation)

Comment: @Jeroen that deserves to be an answer !

Comment: Thank you @JeroenHeier. It works!!

Answer (score -1):

As commented by Jeroen, [this documentation](https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonar-.net-documentation) describes how to connect to SQLServer.

Comment: The new version of the referenced documentation focuses on scanner. It does not mention configuration of SQLServer anymore. 
See https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server.